# Swift, Pass the array in uiPopoverController

Tags: swift, uipopovercontroller, popover

I want to pass the array in my popovercontroller and sort the table view controller, sort it and give it back to the main controller.

### My code for the popovercontroller

```
protocol MyProtocol
{
   func refreshPageController(sortedProperties:[Property])
}
 class SortingPopoverController: UIViewController
{

 @IBOutlet var propertyNameView: UIView!

  @IBOutlet var addressNameView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet var imgSortingPropertyName: UIImageView!

 @IBOutlet var propNameSrtImage: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet var addressSrtImage: UIImageView!

 @IBOutlet var imgTickPropertyName: UIImageView!

 @IBOutlet var imgTickAddress: UIImageView!

    var properties:[Property] = [Property]()

    var utility = Utility()
    var srtProperties : [Property] = []
 var mDelegate: MyProtocol?



 override func viewDidLoad()
    {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      println(properties.count)
      let propertyNameSorting = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "propertyNameSorting:")
      self.propertyNameView.addGestureRecognizer(propertyNameSorting)

        let addressSorting = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "addressSorting:")
      self.addressNameView.addGestureRecognizer(addressSorting)
        imgTickPropertyName.hidden = true
      imgTickAddress.hidden = true

    }


func removeViewColorSelection(uiViewRef: UIView,tickImgShow: UIImageView)
{
    uiViewRef.backgroundColor =  utility.uicolorFromHex(0xF0F0F0)
    uiViewRef.alpha = 0.97
    tickImgShow.hidden = true
}
func addSelectedColorView(uiViewRef: UIView,tickImgShow: UIImageView)
{
    uiViewRef.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    uiViewRef.alpha = 0.97

    tickImgShow.hidden = false
}

func propertyNameSorting(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    println("propertyNameSorting")
    if propertyNameSrt == false
    {
       ascSorting == false
       addSelectedColorView(propertyNameView,tickImgShow: imgTickPropertyName)
       propertyNameSrt =  true
       removeViewColorSelection(addressNameView,tickImgShow: imgTickAddress)
       addressSrt =  false
        if ascSorting == false
        {
            ascSorting = true
            propNameSrtImage.image = UIImage(named: "sorting-ascending-22pt")
            properties.sort(sorterForbuildingAsc)
        }
        else
        {
            ascSorting = false
            propNameSrtImage.image = UIImage(named: "sorting-desending-22pt")
            properties.sort(sorterForbuildingDesc)
        }


    }
    else
    {
        if ascSorting == false
        {
            ascSorting = true
            propNameSrtImage.image = UIImage(named: "sorting-ascending-22pt")
            properties.sort(sorterForbuildingAsc)
        }
        else
        {
            ascSorting = false
            propNameSrtImage.image = UIImage(named: "sorting-desending-22pt")
            properties.sort(sorterForbuildingDesc)
        }

    }

    mDelegate?.refreshPageController(properties)

}
func addressSorting(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    println("addressSorting")
    if addressSrt == false
    {
        ascSorting = false
        addSelectedColorView(addressNameView,tickImgShow: imgTickAddress)
        propertyNameSrt =  false
        removeViewColorSelection(propertyNameView,tickImgShow: imgTickPropertyName)
        addressSrt =  true
        if ascSorting == false
        {
            ascSorting = true
            addressSrtImage.image = UIImage(named: "sorting-ascending-22pt")
        }
        else
        {
            ascSorting = false
            addressSrtImage.image = UIImage(named: "sorting-desending-22pt")
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ascSorting == false
        {
            ascSorting = true
            addressSrtImage.image = UIImage(named: "sorting-ascending-22pt")
        }
        else
        {
            ascSorting = false
            addressSrtImage.image = UIImage(named: "sorting-desending-22pt")
        }

    }


 }
```

### Code to open the controller from the main controller

```
    var sortingPopView = SortingPopoverController(nibName: "PopView",bundle: nil )

    sortingPopView.properties = properties

    var sortingPopoverController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: sortingPopView)

    sortingPopoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSize(width: 250, height: 100)


    sortingPopoverController.presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem(sortingBtn, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up
       , animated: true)
```

Issue is I can't call main view controller method to sort the array.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the delegate on you PopoverViewController.

So when you are calling this in your PopOverController:

```
mDelegate?.refreshPageController(properties)
```

Nothing happens because `mDelegate` is `nil`

When creating the PopoverViewController you have set the delegate:

```
var sortingPopoverController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: sortingPopView)
sortingPopoverController.mDelegate = self
```